# Zero Key and Zero Value in Dictionary when dumping with WinDbg

Tags: asp.net-mvc, debugging, clr, windbg, .net-4.5.2

Basically we are having an ASP.NET MVC application which every now and then have requests hanging for hours leading up to cumulating number of DeadThreads.

I finally got to the bottom of this by dumping the CLRStack of one of those threads with parameters.

```
0:043> !CLRStack -p
OS Thread Id: 0x2010 (43)
        Child SP               IP Call Site
000000237ae4d6d0 000007fe81a1724d System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[[System.__Canon, mscorlib],[System.__Canon, mscorlib]].Insert(System.__Canon, System.__Canon, Boolean)
    PARAMETERS:
        this = <no data>
        key = <no data>
        value = <no data>
        add = <no data>

000000237ae4d760 000007fe84a56877 Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.TelemetryClient.Track(Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Channel.ITelemetry)
    PARAMETERS:
        this (0x000000237ae4d7f0) = 0x0000001f9c954448
        telemetry (0x000000237ae4d7f8) = 0x000000211ca5c840

000000237ae4d7f0 000007fe84db96de Lojaali.Services.Telemetry.AzureTelemetryService+c__DisplayClass9_0.b__0()
    PARAMETERS:
        this = <no data>

000000237ae4d8a0 000007fe829ab39e System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
    PARAMETERS:
        this (0x000000237ae4d910) = 0x000000211ca5cb68

000000237ae4d910 000007fe829aaf25 System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
    PARAMETERS:
        executionContext = <no data>
        callback = <no data>
        state = <no data>
        preserveSyncCtx = <no data>

000000237ae4da70 000007fe829aac7a System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
    PARAMETERS:
        executionContext = <no data>
        callback = <no data>
        state = <no data>
        preserveSyncCtx = <no data>

000000237ae4daa0 000007fe829aa978 System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ExecuteWithThreadLocal(System.Threading.Tasks.Task ByRef)
    PARAMETERS:
        this (0x000000237ae4db80) = 0x000000211ca5cb68
        currentTaskSlot (0x000000237ae4db88) = 0x000000211ca765e8

000000237ae4db80 000007fe829aa610 System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ExecuteEntry(Boolean)
    PARAMETERS:
        this = <no data>
        bPreventDoubleExecution = <no data>

000000237ae4dbc0 000007fe829a98ba System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch()

000000237ae4e128 000007fee0f9a7f3 [DebuggerU2MCatchHandlerFrame: 000000237ae4e128] 
000000237ae4e2b8 000007fee0f9a7f3 [ContextTransitionFrame: 000000237ae4e2b8] 
000000237ae4e4d8 000007fee0f9a7f3 [DebuggerU2MCatchHandlerFrame: 000000237ae4e4d8]
```

So I especially got interested in the TelemetryClient.Tack call

```
000000237ae4d760 000007fe84a56877 Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.TelemetryClient.Track(Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Channel.ITelemetry)
    PARAMETERS:
        this (0x000000237ae4d7f0) = 0x0000001f9c954448
        telemetry (0x000000237ae4d7f8) = 0x000000211ca5c840
```

So I started dumping the dictionaries contained within. For most of them I get keys and values dumped.

However, one thing that baffles me is when I try to dump the dictionary which contains user properties, the last entry seems to have zeroed out key and value:

```
0:043> !DumpObj /d 0000001f9ca54ba0
Name:        System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[[System.String, mscorlib],[System.String, mscorlib]]
MethodTable: 000007fe81fdc808
EEClass:     000007fe819eeef0
Size:        80(0x50) bytes
File:        C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_64\mscorlib\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\mscorlib.dll
Fields:
              MT    Field   Offset                 Type VT     Attr            Value Name
000007fe81b28ef8  4000ca4        8       System.Int32[]  0 instance 0000001f9ca54c08 buckets
000007fe81bb0bb8  4000ca5       10 ...non, mscorlib]][]  0 instance 0000001f9ca54c30 entries
000007fe819bf6f8  4000ca6       38         System.Int32  1 instance                2 count
000007fe819bf6f8  4000ca7       3c         System.Int32  1 instance              288 version
000007fe819bf6f8  4000ca8       40         System.Int32  1 instance               -1 freeList
000007fe819bf6f8  4000ca9       44         System.Int32  1 instance                0 freeCount
000007fe81a0f058  4000caa       18 ...Canon, mscorlib]]  0 instance 000000201c955ae8 comparer
000007fe81e7c618  4000cab       20 ...Canon, mscorlib]]  0 instance 0000000000000000 keys
000007fe81df1b38  4000cac       28 ...Canon, mscorlib]]  0 instance 0000000000000000 values
000007fe819b6088  4000cad       30        System.Object  0 instance 0000000000000000 _syncRoot
0:043> !DumpObj /d 0000001f9ca54c30
Name:        System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2+Entry[[System.String, mscorlib],[System.String, mscorlib]][]
MethodTable: 000007fe81fdcd38
EEClass:     000007fe81fdcc90
Size:        96(0x60) bytes
Array:       Rank 1, Number of elements 3, Type VALUETYPE (Print Array)
Fields:
None
0:043> !DumpArray /d 0000001f9ca54c30
Name:        System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2+Entry[[System.String, mscorlib],[System.String, mscorlib]][]
MethodTable: 000007fe81fdcd38
EEClass:     000007fe81fdcc90
Size:        96(0x60) bytes
Array:       Rank 1, Number of elements 3, Type VALUETYPE
Element Methodtable: 000007fe81fdcc18
[0] 0000001f9ca54c40
[1] 0000001f9ca54c58
[2] 0000001f9ca54c70
0:043> !dumpvc 000007fe81fdcc18  0000001f9ca54c70
Name:        System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2+Entry[[System.String, mscorlib],[System.String, mscorlib]]
MethodTable: 000007fe81fdcc18
EEClass:     000007fe81a6b058
Size:        40(0x28) bytes
File:        C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_64\mscorlib\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\mscorlib.dll
Fields:
              MT    Field   Offset                 Type VT     Attr            Value Name
000007fe819bf6f8  4000cb2       10         System.Int32  1 instance                0 hashCode
000007fe819bf6f8  4000cb3       14         System.Int32  1 instance                0 next
000007fe819b6160  4000cb4        0       System.__Canon  0 instance 0000000000000000 key
000007fe819b6160  4000cb5        8       System.__Canon  0 instance 0000000000000000 value
```

Which leads to my questions. How is this possible? Is it normal or something I should be concerned about? And if I should be concerned, what I'd be looking for in the .NET code to finally pinpoint the issue?